# How to link to another module using Typedoc

Tags: typescript, typedoc

In Typedoc, you can link to another class using:

- `[[ClassName]]`
- `{@link ClassName}`

That class can even belong to another module.

I could however not figure out how to link to

- Another module
- A function exported from another module

So assume you have 2 `d.ts` files:

`Foo.d.ts`

```
/**
 * I want to link to:
 * the [[Bar]] module //does not work
 * the {@link Bar} module //does not work
 * the [[Bar.foobar]] function //does not work
 * the {@link Bar.foobar]] function //does not work
 */
export class Foo{}
```

and `bar.d.ts`

```
export function foobar(): string;
```

What is the correct syntax to do this ? Or is this not supported by Typedoc ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a shortcoming in Typedoc.
Created a [pull request](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/pull/1117) to address this.

If this pull request gets accepted, you should be able to link to a module for which you only have a definition file using `{@link "modulename"}` (yes, the quotes are needed).